# Stop dialog boxes popping up behind dock

Tags: macos

Since upgrading my MacBook Pro to Yosemite I noticed that a lot of programs pop up dialog boxes BEHIND the Dock, making it hard to select buttons. This happens in lots of programs (including some Apple programs). It does not seem to be possible to move the dialog boxes.

[image: Screenshot of dialog box behind dock]

Comment: do you have a screen shot for us?

Comment: I am having this issue, though I have noticed that the dialog boxes get taller between uses. Even if I drag them back to size, it will get taller again. And eventually they end up as seen in the screenshot, behind the dock.

Comment: This helps somewhat. I had not realised you could resize dialogs. In my programs they are fixed size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a OS X 10.10 bug. Apparently they get 22 pixels higher each time.

There is a workaround.

If you hold `Shift` and drag to reduce width this will shrink the dialog box and let you resize.